# conditionally use futurebuilder : Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, future

I have a page where I am fetching data from a server using a `recipeId`. In that page, I use the `complete_model` (that contains all data of the model).

But, while navigating to the page, I already have access to a `slim_model`(contains only id, title, image).

How to make use of the `slim_model` to show `title` and `image` and then populate the rest?

`full_view.dart`:

```dart
class FullView extends StatefulWidget {
  final String id;

  const FullView({Key? key, required this.id}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FullViewState createState() => _FullViewState();
}

class _FullViewState extends State<FullView> {
  late Future<FullDataModel> future;

  @override
  void initState() {
    future = Repository().getModel(widget.id);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<FullDataModel>(
        future: future,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  valueColor:
                      AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(ColorConstants.accent1),
                ),
              );
            default:
              if (snapshot.hasError || snapshot.data == null) {
                return const Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Something went wrong, we are working on fixing it!',
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                final data = snapshot.data!;
                return _body(data, context);
              }
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Navigating to `full_view.dart`,

```dart
 Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) {
                    return FullView(
                      id: slimData.id,
                    );
                  },
                  fullscreenDialog: true));
```

Here, I already have id, title & image data in `slimData`, I want to show that while rest of data loads in `full_view.dart`

The problem is that, I have to use [deep_linking](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/navigation/deep-linking) or sometimes I don't have `slimData` => I only have the `id`.

So, when I have `slimData`, I want to use that to show title and image while rest of data loads using `id`.

If I *don't* have `slimData`, I just want to load everything using `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, when I have slimData, I want to use that to show title and image while rest of data loads using id.

So... just do it? Where you currently have a `CircularProgressIndicator`, insert a conditional and if you *have* SlimData, show that instead of the progress indicator.

Comment: Is that the best approach? I thought I should maintain some state which is half filled initially, but after the future is returned, it gets filled completely!

Comment: Sure, why not. Isn't that the same? You have a "slim" and a "full" variable. if none are filled, show progress indicator, if slim only is filled, show slim, if full is filled, show full.